# How to turn off Database Navigator suggestions in SQL files

Tags: intellij-idea

The Intellij Database Navigator plugin is handy, but every character I type when entering SQL I get prompted with a list of idiotic and irrelevant "suggestions", which I then have to dismiss to see what I'm typing. This "feature" changes the simple task of typing SQL into an intensely annoying and painfully slow process.

How do I turn suggestions off?

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to:

```
Preferences
+-> Tools
  +-> Database Navigator
    +-> Code Completion
```

In the "Filter" panel there, clear the "Basic code completion" and "Extended code completion" selectors by clicking them twice, so that nothing whatsoever remains active.